# Chrome Extension, result of chrome.tabs.query is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a HTML/Javascript novice trying to create a simple Browser Action" chrome extension. I have spent several hours trying to get a piece of it to work. When the popup opens, a button exists called"myBtn", when clicked an element with the ID of "Demo" is supposed to change from text to innerHTML that is the current tabs Url.  I have managed to get to a point where upon clicking the button the default text is replaced with "undefined".  Every change I make to fix this seems to take me backward. I have read many posts on this and other sites but cannot resolve. Anyone see the error in my code preventing the Url from diplaying?

I have "tabs" and "activeTab" permissions in the manifest.  relevant code is:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Sample",
"description": "This extension launches Form on current page",
"version": "1.0",

"icons": { "128": "ITVCicon128x128.png" },

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "ITVCicon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
"permissions": [
      "tabs",
  "activeTab",
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
```

Popup.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p> click the button to get the current tab URL for cut/paste  <button
id="myBtn"> Try it</button> </p>
<p id="demo">Url displays Here</p>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The popup.js containing the functions is:

```
function geturl() {
document.getElementById("demo") .innerHTML = 
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabURL);
});
}

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", geturl);
```

Comment: Tabs.query is asynchronous; it doesn't return anything.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/2336725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your `popup.js` and used `DOMContentLoaded` as Chrome extension suggested like:

**popup.js**:

```
function geturl() {
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
  var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tabURL; //The line I changed to pass the URL to html.
   });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", geturl);
});
```

So you don't have to put your `popup.js` at end of the body in `popup.html`. I changed as:

**popup.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p> click the button to get the current tab URL for cut/paste  
<button id="myBtn"> Try it</button> </p>
<p id="demo">Url displays Here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I tested it works with me.

Comment: Oh lord. No, it is not `DOMContentLoaded` that worked. @gui47, can you _please_ highlight the actually _useful_ code change here? The `DOMContentLoaded` change was not required (script tag is after the element).

Comment: @Xan I've modified the comment that indicates where I changed the code.